# Change body styles from component via angular animation

Tags: css, angular, animation, angular-animations

I have component `modal-window` and i want to make it full screen with angular animation. Now it is implemented as `document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('modal-fullscreen');`. Also in css i have `transition 0.3s` for this animation. Now i need to remake it in angular animation. How i can change styles for `body` directly from `modal-window` component animation?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using `ElementRef` like this -

```
constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {
    console.log(elRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.body);
  }
```

OR

You can simply use

```
document.body
```

But using `document` is not recommended in case of server-side rendering.

## [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypayhz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)